# Force IE 11 "User agent string" using tags

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-browser, compatibility, internet-explorer-11

My website is broken in IE11.

We all know that HTML tags allow developer to force IE compatibility mode; in example

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8, IE=9" />
```

worked great and solved the visualization problems for IE10.

But actually on IE11, even if `Compatibility mode` is set to `IE9`, `User agent string` is set to `default` and javascript doesn't work.
Changing manually `User agent string` to `IE10` solved my problems.

For shure I'm going to solve the real problems that cause website errors, but actually **I need a fast, programatic way to force  "User agent string" to IE10**, since I can't contact every user.

Can someone help?

Comment: The `default` is related to `Document mode`. If you log `navigator.userAgent` when `content="IE=8"`, you'll get `Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; ...)`.

Comment: @Teemu and so? Changing manually "User agent string" solves the problem. Are you suggesting a way to change it programmatically?

Comment: If I've a `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />` in IE11, without touching "Emulation" panel, logging `navigator.userAgent` prints `Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; ...)`, which is not _default_ for IE11. If that is not what you need , I've missunderstood your question...

Comment: What code needs the UA change? Can you edit that code instead of trying to get the UA string to change?

Comment: Removing the MSIE xx.0 from the userAgent string was a bad move for IE 11. It will break lots of JavaScript that relies on assuming the browser is IE if the MSIE exists. Might also break MS's own match in their supplied browsers file for .NET.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solved! Website is up just installing Dotnet framework 4.5 on server**

---

Actually I didn't find a way to force programmatically browsers User agent string (this was the original question).  But repaired website with 0 code..

Just made lot of tests and on one server I found out that website was working, on other server it wasn't.

The "*good server*" was a Win2012, and "*bad servers*" were Win2008. On Win2012 Aspnet 4.5 was running, and on Win2008 it wasn't.

I **installed dotnet framework 4.5** on *bad servers* too, and everything started working!

Answer (score 17):

I also faced the same problem in my 2003 windows server with .net framework 4.0 and after a long research i found the below is helpful...

I created App_Browsers folder and put a browser file named as ie.browser and pasted the below browser definition text and it started working

```
<browsers>
<browser id="IE11" parentID="Mozilla">
<identification>
  <userAgent match="Trident\/7.0; rv:(?'version'(?'major'\d+)(\.(?'minor'\d+)?)(?'letters'\w*))(?'extra'[^)]*)" />
  <userAgent nonMatch="IEMobile" />
</identification>
<capture>
  <userAgent match="Trident/(?'layoutVersion'\d+)" />
</capture>
<capabilities>
  <capability name="browser"              value="IE" />
  <capability name="layoutEngine"         value="Trident" />
  <capability name="layoutEngineVersion"  value="${layoutVersion}" />
  <capability name="extra"                value="${extra}" />
  <capability name="isColor"              value="true" />
  <capability name="letters"              value="${letters}" />
  <capability name="majorversion"         value="${major}" />
  <capability name="minorversion"         value="${minor}" />
  <capability name="screenBitDepth"       value="8" />
  <capability name="type"                 value="IE${major}" />
  <capability name="version"              value="${version}" />
</capabilities>
 </browser>

<!-- Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11,0) like Gecko -->
<browser id="IE110" parentID="IE11">
<identification>
  <capability name="majorversion" match="11" />
</identification>

<capabilities>
  <capability name="ecmascriptversion"    value="3.0" />
  <capability name="jscriptversion"       value="5.6" />
  <capability name="javascript"           value="true" />
  <capability name="javascriptversion"    value="1.5" />
  <capability name="msdomversion"         value="${majorversion}.${minorversion}" />
  <capability name="w3cdomversion"        value="1.0" />
  <capability name="ExchangeOmaSupported" value="true" />
  <capability name="activexcontrols"      value="true" />
  <capability name="backgroundsounds"     value="true" />
  <capability name="cookies"              value="true" />
  <capability name="frames"               value="true" />
  <capability name="javaapplets"          value="true" />
  <capability name="supportsCallback"     value="true" />
  <capability name="supportsFileUpload"   value="true" />
  <capability name="supportsMultilineTextBoxDisplay" value="true" />
  <capability name="supportsMaintainScrollPositionOnPostback" value="true" />
  <capability name="supportsVCard"        value="true" />
  <capability name="supportsXmlHttp"      value="true" />
  <capability name="tables"               value="true" />
  <capability name="supportsAccessKeyAttribute"    value="true" />
  <capability name="tagwriter"            value="System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter" />
  <capability name="vbscript"             value="true" />
</capabilities>
  </browser>
</browsers>
```

Comment: Been searching for this for months! Can't upgrade .NET 4.0 to 4.5 because I have no idea what it will pull down with it. Now finally Ajax works (sort of) with IE 11 - Thank you

Comment: Can this be added without the need for a re-build?

Comment: @Jackson no need to re-build.

Comment: Sorry, but that did not help at all on Server 2003 using IE11.

Comment: I have .net 4.5 installed but old legacy code that checks the agent string still fails with IE 11.  Since I do not have the source code, I used this method and it solved the problem for me. Thank you @Subhranshu

Comment: Where we need to create App_Browsers folder, plz share the path

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to install the entire .NET Framework 4.5, you can just update the .NET Framework 4.0 with this fix from Microsoft http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=39257
In my case this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Put the code in your WebConfig: Working in 2017-2018

```
  <system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=Edge" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```