# OnSelectedIndexChanged not firing in production - IE 11 only

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have a  4.0 .NET site. I have the following element:

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCounty" Width="250" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server"
 OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCounty_SelectedIndexChanged" />
```

This works when running locally in all browsers. Meaning, it hits the ddlCounty_SelectedIndexChanged function. In production, it works with all browsers, other than IE 11. In IE 11, it does not throw any JS errors, but never hits the server when the dropDownList is changed.

I saw this fix: [IE 10 Fix](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx/), which added 2 App_browser files to my project. I tried this, but it did not work. Furthermore, I have verified that it works correctly in IE 10.

So basically, this issue only occurs in IE 11 (non compatibility mode).

Anyone have an idea of what I should try next?

**EDIT:** additional code that was request:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

Comment: can you show me starting portion of your aspx page.

Comment: it does not postback at all or it postbacks and the event is not fired?

Comment: It does not postback at all. In the network tab of the IE dev tools, there is not a request. If I set it to IE 10, I see the request.

Comment: @PFranchise atleast 10 lines form starting portion of your aspx page please.

Comment: @BhaveshKachhadiya I added all the code from the start to the element in question. Please note, I inherited this code, so I did not write this somewhat sub-par code.

Comment: @PFranchise actually what I want to know if `<!Doctype>` tag of the page. But as I can see you are using master page. the doctype tag may be defined in your master page.

Comment: @BhaveshKachhadiya Oh, my fault. I replaced my code with my Doctype tag. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: @PFranchise just try this `<!DOCTYPE html>` tag. instead of old one.

Comment: @BhaveshKachhadiya That does not appear to have fixed the issue.

Comment: I am also having same Issue in IE11...How did you fixed that finally??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just installing .NET 4.5 on the server (did not change the version the site was using) and the issue went away.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem with IE (I think all versions as IE is horrible). Try clearing all cookies and browser history. You might need to change the settings. What I did to fix this issue was adding this line of code in the behind in the Page_Load.

```
Response.CacheControl = "No-cache";
```

Caching is basically IE's try at being quick. As far as I know, IE is the only browser that caches and this has caused browser problems only in IE. Try those steps and see if you have any luck.

EDIT: I just saw that you are using an update panel. Not sure if you have tried to use a trigger or not. This is how I have done mine..

```
<trigger>
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlCounty" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
<trigger>
```

Or you can do it behind code..

```
UpdatePanel1.Triggers.Add(new AsyncPostBackTrigger()
{
    ControlID = ddlCounty.UniqueID,
    EventName = "SelectedIndexChanged",
});
```

But I'm just throwing ideas out there. This is one thing I'd try to see if it's a possible work around. No promises.

Comment: I don't think it is related to caching. If I browse privately, I still have the issue. Also, I tried deleting my cache and still experienced the issue. IE caching can definitely be troublesome though.

Comment: IE is not the only browser that caches.  All browsers cache.  IE does however have some quirky and unpredictable caching behavior.  This Q doesn't seem like a caching issue though.

Comment: @pseudocoder that's true. I misspoke. IE just does it horribly.

Comment: Take a look at my edit. Try adding a trigger maybe to your update panel.

Comment: Good answer. Cache was my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same issue, event for dropdown,checkbox not firing only in IE11, 
that too works fine if i chagnes F12 IE console UserAgentString to IE10
Refer this Hotfix for IE11, do as mentioned in that link, it will fix this issue

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20422240/2089963