# IE11 User Agent

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, internet-explorer

I have a MVC web application that uses the 2010 report viewer.
written in C# VS2010

IE11 users are having difficulty loading the page containing the control, it sits indefinitely on the "Loading..." indicator.

I have managed to track this down to others having similar issues with the user agent being the culprit.

So to test I pulled up the development tools, changed the user agent to anything other than default, and viola, page loaded without issue.

So all of the typical ways to address this such as .NET 4.5.1 installed on server (Server 2008 R2 STD), and APP_Browsers directory and an ie.browser file, `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />` as the first line of the  section, etc... all have failed. Likewise I have tried putting the browser file in the .NET directory with its native files, to no end, and I have compiled them into the GAC with no luck either.

In all these cases the navigator.userAgent query on the java console reports to be "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; rv:11.0) like Gecko"

If I change the user agent string to IE10 in emulator I get "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0)"

So changing in emulator works, and the change itself does what I need, but I cannot seem to get it to override from ANYWHERE other than emulator.

The question is almost the same as this one, however none of the suggestions there seem to fix it.

[Force IE 11 "User agent string" using tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20120941/force-ie-11-user-agent-string-using-tags)

Code behind on the page is very basic, so not much there to troubleshoot.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="DashBoard.aspx.cs" Inherits="AwReporting.Pages.DashBoard" Trace="False" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
    Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="CACHE-CONTROL" content="NO-CACHE" />
    <meta http-equiv="PRAGMA" content="NO-CACHE" />
</head>
<body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="Dashboard" runat="server" Height="500px"
            ShowBackButton="False" ShowExportControls="False" ShowFindControls="False" ShowPageNavigationControls="False"
            ShowPrintButton="False" ShowRefreshButton="False" ShowZoomControl="False" Width="100%"
            ShowToolBar="False" SizeToReportContent="True">
            <LocalReport DisplayName="Dashboard" ReportPath=".\\app_data\\rpt\\DashBoard.rdlc">
            </LocalReport>
        </rsweb:ReportViewer>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

any other suggestions or suggestions to what I may have botched in the other troubleshooting would be greatly appreciated....

Comment: What happens if you change your DOCTYPE to the HTML5 DOCTYPE?

Comment: I would poke around in this SO question. It looks like it might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20120941/force-ie-11-user-agent-string-using-tags?lq=1

Comment: @Hardrada: That is the same one I posted in the original post, I tried those things and it did not work on any of the suggestions. That is why I asked for any more suggestions. And Adam: I will try that ASAP and post back, thank you.

Comment: Changing the doctype did not resolve the issue.

Comment: I have tracked this down to the RDLC file itself O.o I have recreated it to function exactly like it was, and the new one works. What would I even look for in the file that could have caused a behavior like this. All of the other RDLC files were created at the same time, and all of them work without issues. So very strange... I would like to at least know WHY this one had a specific issue with the user agent...

Answer (score 0):

The issue came down to something in the RDLC report file.
It was a very simple single tablix and a textbox, I have no idea what the cause of the internal failure was, however recreating the report in the same VS installation it had been originally created in, resolved the issue.

If I track down the exact failure in the report file, I will post back for the benefit of others in the future than may have the same issue.