# Enforce meta tags in a javascript pop up

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I am trying to make an older website work on IE 11 and was able to achieve this using :

```
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=EmulateIE7"/>
      </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

in web.config (i am using asp.net) for enforcing "document mode" and using this https://stackoverflow.com/a/20422240/1531476 to enforce user agent string .

However for a particular scenario when i open a pop up using window.open (javascript) "document mode" gets set to "edge" and does not adheres to what i enforced using httpProtocol tag in web.config.

I also visited this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/18982627/1531476 and concluded that i cannot add meta tags to a pop up window using javacsript.

Can someone please point me in the right direction so that i can solve this issue.
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research i concluded that it is futile to force meta tags on the HTML popups opened using JavaScript.
In this particular case i added a static HTML page and inserted some HTML dynamically,  instead of an HTML popup of window.open().
Hope this helps someone.