# widgEditor is not displaying in IE 11, but working in Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, angular, typescript

I am using widgEditor in my website. It is displaying in Chrome, but not in IE 11.

```
<div class="task-desc">
    <label class="hdr" for="details">Details</label>
    <form id="widgeForm" action="javascript:void(0)">
        <fieldset>                        
            <textarea id="noise" name="noise" class="widgEditor nothing">{{details}}</textarea>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="submit" hidden>
            <input id="widgeSubmit" type="submit" value="Check"/>
        </fieldset>
    </form>                
</div>
```

Now it looks like below, but the toolbar images are not displayed. All the toolbar buttons are working, but images of the toolbar are not displaying. How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Make sure I.E is not in compability mode IE<11. Open console and take a look at Emulation tab.

Comment: But how can I make the Emulation tab default mode to  10 .Now it display the toolbar but images are not displaying.

Comment: You can force IE11 by adding a `<meta>` at the first line of your `<head>`. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18588769/forcing-ie-11-to-behave-as-ie-10

Comment: Hi Alexis,Here is first line of head tag <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE10"/>,But widgeditor is not displaying.When I go to Emulation tab and select 10,then It is displaying.I want it to be display by code not by Emulation tab.

Comment: use IE 11 `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`

Comment: Hi Alexis,I have made changes in head section meta tag but toolbar is not displaying. <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>

Comment: There's no error in console ? It's not just due to compability mode then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125610/discussion-between-mohit-and-alexis).